# OWASP ASVS V10.4 Verify that backend TLS connection failures are logged ---- How?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, audit, owasp

we are working on an ASP.NET project that is required to comply with the OWASP ASVS checklist. One of the term is "**Verify that backend TLS connection failures are logged.**" I couldn't find a way to achieve this but the customer is holding us to it. Any suggestions/references? Sample code will be even better.

Here's the link to the owasp thing:
http://code.google.com/p/owasp-asvs/wiki/Verification_V10

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I agree this is badly worded. There is a revamp of the ASVS at the moment. Come on by and help us make things more concrete and testable.

In your instance, TLS connections are typically maintained by the operating system on behalf of application and library code that rarely if ever makes any real effort to vaidate that the TLS connection is what it says it is on the tin. Browsers are getting better at warning their users, but libraries are shockingly bad and applications that call them worse at checking for end to end errors and making wise security decisions about the state of the connection. Even basic things like certificate revocation should be a no brainer, but so few libraries enable this by default.

We see this every day in mobile phone apps - it's trivial to get most mobile apps to connect via MITM proxies that don't provide any user feedback that the connection is untrustworthy.

I'd like to see this requirement to be:

"User agent software (mobile app, browser, web service, library) MUST make it clear to the end user in terms they can readily understand that the connection is untrustworthy, and furthermore reject the connection, or to require user intervention to establish an insecure connection. Such failed or insecure connections should be logged."

This would make sure that - regardless if it's the OS, the library or the application - someone owns this interaction, and that is has a clear security objective (no untrusted connections), a usability control that favors security, and lastly a detection control to allow pre-incident monitoring and post-incident re-construction if a user makes a terribly poor choice (for we know they always do given the chance).

I know this doesn't answer your question per se, but you don't mention if you use OpenSSL or WCF or ... I'd be happy to contribute a code snippet if you let me know the platform you'd like.

Comment: I think what's missing from these guidelines is a definition of "backend" (and under which circumstances TLS is needed for these connections).